# How to increase the size of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to increase the size of an array list but it doesnt seem to want to work.

I am doing this:

```
    final int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 27;
    ArrayList adjacencyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
```

But when I try to add something with the add that has two paramters, (index,value) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you are adding the something with two parameters?

Comment: adjacencyList.add(u,v);

Comment: You need something like this `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[25]));` to init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have established the initial capacity of the `ArrayList`, but there are still no items in the list.  You can't insert an item before index 1 if it doesn't exist yet.

You must use [the one-argument `add` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) to append to the end of the list, or supply `0` as the index in [the two-argument `add` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), so that there is something in the list.

Comment: I want to add multiple items at each position in the array list though.

Comment: When created, an `ArrayList`'s size is 0, even if its capacity is 27.  There is no set positioning you can set it to like an array.  You'll have to `add` them in order.

Comment: When you say "I want to add multiple items at each position in the array list", are you looking for something like a List<List<Foo>>? And if that's the case, do you really need a List on the outside, or would something like Map<SomeKey, List<Foo>> work for you? If what you really need is a map of something to list of something else, then consider using the Guava MultiMap. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Answer (score 2):

Well, If you really want to do this.

You need to Intialise the Array with 'Integers' like '0' or so
and then instead of add() method use the set(int index, E element) method which Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

Any index at which you see '0' is equivalent to empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the equivalent of `adjacencyList.add(1, 1)`? If so, you're trying to add to an empty list at index `1`, which doesn't exist. Just call `adjacencyList.add(<value>)`.

Also, include the generic type at initialization:

```
ArrayList<Integer> adjacencyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
```

PS. You don't usually need to adjust the initial capacity of an `ArrayList` unless you know the list will rarely end up being small.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

If you're going to insert something at a certain position, you need to have elements stored up to the point in the list already.